# Multitasking while sending camera frames sockets

Tags: python, opencv, sockets

I'm working on Security camera system using tkinter and I'm sending webcam frames using cv2 from server to client every second, I want that adminstraitor in the system can create or remove users

Example video from the code: https://youtu.be/n55Nl6Pq8S8

My server is getting messages from the client and handling it
code from server:

```
        elif message[0] == "get_cam":
            cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
            while (cam.isOpened()):
                img, frame = cam.read()
                frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=320)
                a = pickle.dumps(frame)  # serialize frame to bytes
                message = struct.pack("Q", len(a)) + a  # pack the serialized data
                try:
                    conn.sendall(message)  # send message or data frames to client
                except Exception as e:
                    x = 0
```

client code:

```
def display_system():
root1 = tk.Tk()
root1.title("Secure4U")
root1.geometry("1200x600")
message = "rank#get"
my_socket.send(message.encode())
user_rank = my_socket.recv(1024).decode() # Getting user's rank
message = "name#get"
my_socket.send(message.encode())
user_name = my_socket.recv(1024).decode()  # Getting user's personal name
fontStyle = tkFont.Font(family="Lucida Grande", size=20)

# logo
img = tk.PhotoImage(file="logo.png")
logo_panel1 = tk.Label(root1, image=img)
logo_panel1.image = img
logo_panel1.place(x=0, y=0)

log_out_button = tk.Button(root1, text='Logout', height=2, width=10, command=lambda: (root1.destroy()))
log_out_button.place(x=1110, y=10)

# register button for admins
if user_rank == "Admin":
    reg_button = tk.Button(root1, text='Create New User', height=2, width=15, command=lambda: (register()))
    reg_button.place(x=988, y=10)
    del_button = tk.Button(root1, text='Delete User', height=2, width=10, command=lambda: (delete()))
    del_button.place(x=900, y=10)

# logged user
show_user_logged = tk.Label(root1, text="Hello " + user_name + ",", font=fontStyle)
show_user_logged.place(x=2, y=135)

# logged user's rank
show_user_rank = tk.Label(root1, text="Rank: " + str(user_rank), font=fontStyle)
show_user_rank.place(x=2, y=175)

# show camera
my_socket.send("get_cam#rn".encode())
thread_cam = threading.Thread(target=camera, args=(root1,))
thread_cam.daemon = True
thread_cam.start()

root1.mainloop()  # run tkinter display

def camera(root):
    data = b""
    payload_size = struct.calcsize("Q")  # Q: unsigned long long integer(8 bytes)

    frame = np.random.randint(0, 255, [100, 100, 3], dtype='uint8')

    cam1 = tk.Label(root)
    cam1.place(x=300, y=100)

    # Business logic to receive data frames, and unpak it and de-serialize it and show video frame on client side
    while True:
        while len(data) < payload_size:
            packet = my_socket.recv(4 * 1024)  # 4K, range(1024 byte to 64KB)
            if not packet: break
            data += packet  # append the data packet got from server into data variable
        packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]  # will find the packed message size i.e. 8 byte, we packed on server side.
        data = data[payload_size:]  # Actual frame data
        msg_size = struct.unpack("Q", packed_msg_size)[0]  # message size
        # print(msg_size)

        while len(data) < msg_size:
            data += my_socket.recv(4 * 1024)  # will receive all frame data from client socket
        frame_data = data[:msg_size]  # recover actual frame data
        data = data[msg_size:]
        frame = pickle.loads(frame_data)  # de-serialize bytes into actual frame type
        img_update = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(frame))
        cam1.configure(image=img_update)
        cam1.image = img_update
        cam1.update()
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
        if key == ord('q'):  # press q to exit video
            break
```

I have no idea how I can do it multitasking and make it that the server can send the frames and get other messages from the client in the same time and also handle them

Comment: "I want that adminstraitor in the system can create or remove users"? ok so what prevents you from implementing that functionality? Stack Overflow does not exist to give individual programming help, or to teach you programming. it exists to document specific solutions to specific programming problems. your question doesn't fit the site's purpose. please review https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic there are sites better suited to your situation

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I don't need in that functioning, only to stop the error "frame = pickle.loads(frame_data)  # de-serialize bytes into actual frame type
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xfa'." from happening

Comment: why didn't you say that in the first place? so your question isn't about opencv or sockets, it's about pickle! I'd recommend starting a new question and focusing on that. and *please* read [mre].